# How to Get Image position in ImageView

Tags: iphone

I use a full screen imageView to display the image, as follows:

```
UIImageView*imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)]
imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imageView.image=srcImage;
```

As the srcImage size differs, its position (frame) in the imageView differs, how can I
get the position of the image in imageView?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the math yourself. Calculate the aspect ratio of your image and compare with the aspect ratio of the image view's bounds.