# How to find back the real position on the image on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

Here is the view I got, I got a `layer view`, detect user touch, and a `image view`, which showing the image. The `layer view` is cover on top of the `image view`. The `image view`'s image is aspect fit. So, it won't lost the ratio. If in my `layer view` touch on `100, 240`, it is a `layer view` coordinate, but not the image's coordinate. I would like to know how to convert the `layer view`'s coordinate to a image's coordinate. In this example, the image size may be 180*180, so, the coordinate in `layer view` in the `image` is `60, 90`.

Thanks.[image]

Comment: "After the view, which is a big UIImageView, and the image is aspect fit." - What?

Comment: What is 100,240? The image is gendered in you (apparently full screen) image view. It isn't clear what you want to calculate.

Comment: Sorry, updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm understanding this question correctly, you want to take a point, which is currently in relation to the layer's coordinate system, and convert it to the image view's coordinate system?

In that case, there are a couple of ways to do this.

Easiest is to use `convertPoint:fromView:` or `convertPoint:toView:`

> CGPoint imageViewTouchPoint = [layerView convertPoint:touchPoint fromView:imageView];
>
> CGPoint imageViewTouchPoint = [imageView convertPoint:touchPoint toView:layerView];

Either one should work.

**EDIT** - I realize now that this is only if the `UIImageView` has the same frame as the `UIImage`, which you said it might not, due to the `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` property.

In this case, unless I'm mistaken, the image frame is calculated inside the `UIImageView` `drawRect:` method and isn't a property that gets set. This means you'll have to calculate this on your own.

Definitely get the `imageViewTouchPoint` from one of the methods above (just in case you want to use the same logic on a `UIImageView` which isn't the full screen size).

You will then need to calculate the scaled image frame. There are a couple of ways to do this. Some people go brute force and manually calculate based on which side of the image is longer, then determining which side should be scaled. Then they calculate the origin by by centering the image and subtracting the image and image view's sides and dividing by two.

I like to write as little code as possible if it's unnecessary, even if it means importing a framework. If you import `AVFoundation` you get a method `AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect` which you can use to actually calculate the scaled rectangle in one line of code.

> CGRect imageRect = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(image.size, imageView.frame);

Whichever method you use, you will then simply translate your touched point with the scaled image origin:

> CGPoint imageTouchPoint = CGPointMake(imageViewTouchPoint.x - imageRect.origin.x, imageViewTouchPoint.y - imageRect.origin.y);

Comment: yes, but the problem is , I would like to have the point of the `image`, instead of the `imageView`.

Comment: Ahh, now I understand. In that case, I am almost certain you'll have to calculate this by hand as images are sized upon rendering and so the `UIImageView` doesn't store this information anywhere.

Comment: I updated my answer to provide a method for calculating this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the math yourself. Calculate the aspect ratio of your image and compare with the aspect ratio of the image view's bounds.

Look at this question: [How to Get Image position in ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918919/how-to-get-image-position-in-imageview)

After searching more, got a hack:

```
CGSize imageInViewSize = [photo resizedImageWithContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit bounds:imageView.size interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationNone].size;


CGRect overlayRect = CGRectMake((imageView.frame.size.width - imageInViewSize.width) / 2,
                                        (imageView.frame.size.height - imageInViewSize.height) / 2, 
                                        imageInViewSize.width, 
                                        imageInViewSize.height);

NSLog(@"Frame of Image inside UIImageView: Left:%f Top:%f Width:%f Height:%f \n", overlayRect.origin.x, overlayRect.origin.y, overlayRect.size.width, overlayRect.size.height);
```